# How to define constant partition key in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

Have small table I'd like to confine to single partition in Cassandra. I tried various constants as partition key, but Cassandra rejects as invalid. Eg `primary key(1, other_column)`, `primary key(true, other_column)`, `primary key('1', other_column)`. Is there some way to limit a table to a single partition w/o adding a dummy constant column to the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can't define constant value as partition key or any other column**

Instead define a normal column (i.e partition) as partition key and every time you insert/update or delete use a constant value.

Example :

Let's create a table with a column named `partition` and make that as partition key.

Now CRUD Operation :

```
INSERT INTO small_table(partition, other_column) VALUES(1, ?);
SELECT * FROM small_table WHERE partition = 1;
UPDATE small_table SET other_column = ? WHERE partition = 1;
DELETE FROM small_table WHERE partition = 1;
```

Note : *This is a bad design, your data will not distribute across cluster. all your select, insert, update, delete operation will execute on the host and replica that contains this data*